# One Drive Incremental Changes Using MS Graph API Delta Endpoint

Tags: c#, filter, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, delta

I am trying to get delta changes in my One Drive Root using the following MS Graph API:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/drive/root/delta

I get JSON response:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
"@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/drive/root/delta",
"value": [
    {
    {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
        "createdDateTime": "2020-08-24T14:27:07Z",
        "eTag": "\"{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX},1\"",
        "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-08-24T14:27:07Z",
        "name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx",
        "webUrl": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxx",
        "cTag": "\"c:{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx},0\"",
        "size": 4500070,
        "createdBy": {
            "application": {
                "displayName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
            },
            "user": {
                "email": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "displayName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx"
            }
        },
        "lastModifiedBy": {
            "application": {
                "displayName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "user": {
                "email": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "displayName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            }
        },
        "parentReference": {
            "driveType": "business",
            "driveId": ""XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"",
            "id": ""XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"",
            "path": "/drive/root:",
            "siteId": ""XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX""
        },
        "fileSystemInfo": {
            "createdDateTime": "2020-08-24T14:27:07Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-08-24T14:27:07Z"
        },
        "folder": {
            "childCount": 21
        }
    },
    {
    ...
    
    ...
    },
    ...
    ....
    ..
```

It seems as per documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters)
that this method supports the $select, $expand, and $top OData query parameters to customize the response.
But it does not support $filter query parmeter.
Is that correct ???

If yes, what is the best approach to filter the items in the response on the basis of the path of Parent i.e. parentReference/path.

Also, is it posible to request a delta for a secific folder item in One Drive other than drive/root.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Gagan